# PHP - Namespaces in XML - Start element with namespace

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to achieve below format in XML (generated with PHP):

```
<ns0:XmlInterchange xmlns:ns0="http://www.website.com" xmlns:ext="http://www.website.com">
     <ns0:InterchangeInfo>
        <ns0:Date>2017-06-28T11:33:15</ns0:Date>
        <ns0:XmlType>Verbose</ns0:XmlType>
      <ns0:Source>
         <ns0:EnterpriseCode>DSV</ns0:EnterpriseCode>
         <ns0:OriginServer>ESB</ns0:OriginServer>
      </ns0:Source>
      <ns0:EDIOrganisation EDICode="0"/>
   </ns0:InterchangeInfo>
</ns0:XmlInterchange>
```

So, right now, all I have is this:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$rss = $xml->createElement('ns0');
$rss->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ns0', 'http://website.com');
$rss->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ext', 'http://website.com');
$xml->appendChild($rss);
```

Which outputs this:

```
<ns0 xmlns:ns0="http://website.com" xmlns:ext="http://website.com"/>
```

The problem above is the beginning of the `XML`. It needs to be:

```
 <ns0:XmlInterchange xmlns:ns0="http://website.com" xmlns:ext="http://website.com"/>
```

How can I add the `:XmlInterchange` namespace to the beginning of the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use :

```
$rss = $xml->createElementNS('ns0', 'ns0:XmlInterchange');
```

instead of

```
$rss = $xml->createElement('ns0');
```